# Reduction of DEs to Bessel equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

A question in my textbook asks me to write down the general solution to:

$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2\frac{dR(x)}{dx}) + [k^2x^2 - n(n+1)]R(x) = 0$ in terms of Bessel functions.

Now two similar questions before this one were:

$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2\frac{dR}{dx}) + [x^2 - n(n+1)]R = 0$ which I found the solution to be $R(x) = AJ_{n+\frac{1}{2}}(x) + BY_{n+\frac{1}{2}}(x)$

and

$x^2\frac{d^2R(x)}{dx^2}) + x\frac{dR(x)}{dx} + [k^2x^2 - v^2]R(x) = 0$ which I found the solution to be $R = AJ_v(kx) + BY_v(kx)$

so would the solution to the question be: $R = AJ_{n+\frac{1}{2}}(kx) + BY_{n+\frac{1}{2}}(kx)$ ? and if not, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differential equation
\begin{align}
D(x^{2} \ Dy) + [(kx)^{2} - n(n+1)]y = 0
\end{align}
can be placed in familiar form by making the substitution 
\begin{align}
y(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} f(x).
\end{align}
It is seen that
\begin{align}
Dy(x) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \left( Df - \frac{x}{2} f \right) \\
D^{2} y(x) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \left( D^{2} f - \frac{1}{x} Df + \frac{3}{2 x^{2}} f \right)
\end{align}
for which the differential equation becomes
\begin{align}
x^{2} D^{2} f + x D f + [ (kx)^{2} - \left( n + \frac{1}{2}\right)^{2} ] f = 0.
\end{align}
The solution to this differential equation is given by
\begin{align}
f(x) = A J_{n+1/2}(kx) + B Y_{n+1/2}(kx).
\end{align}
Using this in the transformation made the solution for $y$ becomes
\begin{align}
y(x) = \frac{A}{\sqrt{x}} J_{n+1/2}(kx) + \frac{B}{\sqrt{x}} Y_{n+1/2}(kx).
\end{align}
Without loss of generality, this may be seen in the form
\begin{align}
y(x) = A \sqrt{ \frac{\pi}{2 x} } J_{n+1/2}(kx) + B \sqrt{ \frac{\pi}{2 x} } Y_{n+1/2}(kx).
\end{align}
These solutions are known as the spherical Bessel functions and are represented as, in solution form,
\begin{align}
y(x) = A j_{n}(kx) + B y_{n}(kx).
\end{align}